# How to access function in Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How can I get `getSum()`'s value in a Handlebars template?

When I call `{{App.Address.getsum}}` it will return string. it included all the function part.
How can I get the correct value?

I tried to get value for getsum.

```
App.Address = {    
    details: [
        {
            "time": "11.56",
            "size": 10540,
            "price": "789.5",
            "direction": "Down",
            "side": "Sell",
            "change": "9.5",
            "check": "true"
        },
        {
            "time": "14.56",
            "size": 145500,
            "price": "555.5",
            "direction": "Up",
            "side": "Buy",
            "change": "5.5"
        }, {
            "time": "15.56",
            "size": 15550,
            "price": "456",
            "direction": "Down",
            "side": "Sell",
            "change": "9.5",
            "check": "true"
        }, {
            "time": "11.45",
            "size": 14550,
            "price": "23.5",
            "direction": "Down",
            "side": "Buy",
            "change": "5.5"
        }, {
            "time": "11.22",
            "size": 54500,
            "price": "2.5",
            "direction": "Down",
            "side": "Sell",
            "change": "6.8",
            "check": "true"
        }, {
            "time": "20.56",
            "size": 110550,
            "price": "11.8",
            "direction": "Down",
            "side": "Buy",
            "change": "3.5"
        }, {
            "time": "11.13",
            "size": 14343432,
            "price": "88.8",
            "direction": "Down",
            "side": "Buy",
            "change": "2.5"
        },

        {
            "time": "13.56",
            "size": 23423434,
            "price": "855.8",
            "direction": "Up",
            "side": "Sell",
            "change": "1.8",
            "check": "true"
        }, {
            "time": "11.33",
            "size": 233,
            "price": "86.5",
            "direction": "Up",
            "side": "Buy",
            "change": "6.8"
        }, {
            "time": "11.56",
            "size": 153243,
            "price": "28.5",
            "direction": "Up",
            "side": "Buy",
            "change": "5.8"
        }, {
            "time": "11.15",
            "size": 1344,
            "price": "456",
            "direction": "Down",
            "side": "Buy",
            "change": "1.1"
        }
    ],
    getSum: function() {
        var details = this.details;
        var sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0, length = details.length; i < length; i++) {
            sum += parseInt(details[i].size, 10);
        }
        return sum;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Just assign to a variable / property? `template({myValue: App.Address.getSum()})` . http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: At some point in human history some people decided that calling functions inside templates should be a bad practice, hence the inability to do so in libraries like Handlebars. Instead you can do what @FelixKling suggested or create a helper; more about helpers here: http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers

Comment: Also, here is a complete tutorial: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the function as a property.

```
getSum: function() {
        var details = this.details;
        var sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0, length = details.length; i < length; i++) {
            sum += parseInt(details[i].size, 10);
        }
        return sum;
    }.property()
```

Then you can call it by {{App.Address.getSum}} in the template.